# Regex for searching inside a string

Tags: regex

I am not really good at regex.

Can someone help me with generating regex regarding this problem:

If I input lets say "an"

It should match Annie but not Stan or Jan.

I will just use the regex in my searching module.

Thanks.

Comment: Use starts with anchor `^an`

Comment: how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: It depends on where you are using the regex. I think it is difficult to help without knowing the programming language you are using regex in. As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
\ban\B
```

You can use this.`\b` will make sure word starts with `an` and `\B` will makee sure it does not end with `an`.TO make it case sensitive use `i` flag.

or

```
\b[aA][nN]\B
```

Comment: If the pattern is used in HTML5, there is no `i` modifier there.

Answer (score 0):

```
^an
```

Would match any string starting with an "an".
Answering your comment on the case sensitivity, it would depend on the regex parser. Ex with `grep` you can pass the `-i` flag.

Comment: It won't match `Annie`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^a|An
```

It is case insensitive

Comment: This will find a match in `BAn` (a next to impossible case, but the regex will work here).

Comment: Okay so it's really unclear what's actually being asked...x_x

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to achieve it.

However, I would suggest you to spend only 30 minutes on http://regexone.com. Get some hands on it. This will really help to get head start on Regex.